# Override native Promise implementation

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, pdf.js

I'm using pdfjs to display pdfs in the browser and I have some problems on Edge and Internet Explorer due to the native Promises. I heard that bluebird polyfill will fix this issues. I simply add a reference to bluebird.min.js in pdfjs viewer.html, but it seems that the native promises are used again. Is there a way to override this, to use the promise implementation from bluebird ?

Comment: Did you import bluebird before anything else?

Comment: I imported the js file in the html file. `<script src="bluebird.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Right, did you do it _before_ you imported pdfjs?

Comment: It is the first imported script in viewer.html

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you succeed?

Comment: Try importing the `bluebird.min.js` in `worker_loader.js` also, by adding the line `importScripts('path/to/bluebird.min.js');`